# sql programming all type

Tags: sql

Write a query to display list of students name who all are from IT department. Sort the result based on students name in descending.

Comment: Please refer : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This site is for narrowly-focused question. Also, always search Stack Overflow before posting. Voting to close.

Comment: Elaborate more with details like what is the table structure ?

Comment: Good question but where is your effort ? Did you try any attempt?

Answer (score -1):

This query will work for any rdbms and any schema (I assume that's what you are after here)

```
 select studentid, firstname, surname 
    from tblStudent s 
    inner join tblStudentDepartment sd on s.studentid = sd.studentid 
    inner join tblDepartment d on sd.departmentid = d.departmentid 
    where d.department = 'IT'
```